# How to access a certain array inside an array: PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I know this is pretty stupid but i'm wondering how to access the FIFTH array inside this array.

```
    array(1) {
          [0] = > string(3)"913"
    }
    array(2) {
          [0] = > string(3)"913"
          [1] = > string(2)"95"
    }
    array(3) {
          [0] = > string(3)"913" 
          [1] = > string(2)"95"
          [2] = > string(1)"3"
    }
    array(4) {
          [0] = > string(3)"913"
          [1] = > string(2)"95"
          [2] = > string(1)"3"
          [3] = > string(1)"6"
    }
    array(5) {
          [0] = > string(3)"913"
          [1] = > string(2)"95"
          [2] = > string(1)"3"
          [3] = > string(1)"6"
          [4] = > string(1)"0"
    }
```

can't seem to access it with `<?php echo $array[5]; ?>` sorry again for the dumb question

Comment: How about `print_r( $array[4] );` ?

Comment: Arrays in PHP are zero based. This means you would use `$array[4]` to get the fifth array.

Comment: undefined offset. really weird :(

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right array?

Comment: yep. the array $array contains the json above, i am really stumped by this.

Comment: Is this output from inside a foreach by any chance?

Comment: Can you do a `var_export` on the array and show the results?

Comment: royal yes you're right, i'll check dainis

Comment: This is not an array. Otherwise it would be `0=>array(0=>,1=>,2=>),1=>array(0=>,1=>...)`. Everytime the loop repeats, you recieve the output. If you want to access `$array[4]`. Do it outside the foreach

Comment: dainis `array ( 0 => '913', ) array ( 0 => '913', 1 => '95', ) array ( 0 => '913', 1 => '95', 2 => '3', ) array ( 0 => '913', 1 => '95', 2 => '3', 3 => '6', ) array ( 0 => '913', 1 => '95', 2 => '3', 3 => '6', 4 => '0', ) `

Comment: @Growlithe either count the iterations and input when on fifth or access $array[4] outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
    array("913"),
    array("913", "95"),
    array("913", "95", "3"),
    array("913", "95", "3", "6"),
    array("913", "95", "3", "6", "0")
);

var_dump($arr);
//output
/*
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "913"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "913"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "95"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "913"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "95"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "913"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "95"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "913"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "95"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
*/


print_r($arr[4]);
//Output : Array ( [0] => 913 [1] => 95 [2] => 3 [3] => 6 [4] => 0 ) 

// loop through 5th array
foreach($arr[4] as $key => $val) {
    echo $key." => ".$val."<br/>";
}

// Output
/*    
0 => 913
1 => 95
2 => 3
3 => 6
4 => 0
*/

echo "Third value : ".$arr[4][2];
//Third value : 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are zero-indexed. Which means 0 is the first item, 1 the second, etc.

Try `<?php print_r($array[4]) ?>` :)

Comment: undefined offset. really weird :(

Answer (score 0):

By default, array values start with `0`, so the 5th element would be #4:

```
print_r( $array[4] );
```

Comment: undefined offset. really weird :(